True/False: Given an edge $(u,v)$: no path exists from $u$ to $v$ in the residual graph w.r.t a max flow $\iff$ $(u,v)$ crosses some minimum cut
I was asked to show if this is true or false. I believe it is true, but proving it seems difficult. Is it true and how might one show this?

Denote $\delta^-(S)$ the set of "forward edges" (edges that start in $S$ and end in $\bar{S}$) and $\delta^-(S)$ the set of "backward edges" (edges that start in $\bar{S}$ and end in $S$).
$\Leftarrow$:
We assume that $(u,v)$ is in (= crosses) some minimum cut, and want to show that no residual path exists from $u$ to $v$.
Indeed, let $(S, \bar{S})$ be some min cut that $(u,v)$ crosses. Thus, $u \in S$, $v\in\bar{S}$.
Assume, by way of contradiction, that there exists a path from $u$ to $v$ in the residual graph. Since it starts in $S$ and ends in $\bar{S}$, there exist edge(s) that cross the cut. Let $(x,y)$ be the first such edge (so $x\in S$, $y\in\bar{S}$). There are now two options:

If $(x,y)$ is a forward edge (meaning: it's in the residual graph because of a parallel edge $(x,y)$ in the original graph that is not saturated) then there exists an edge $(x,y)$ in the original graph that crosses the minimum cut $S$ (shorthand for $(S, \bar{S})$), but an edge that crosses a minimum cut is entirely saturated, in which case the edge $(x,y)$ doesn't exist in the residual graph, but that is a contradiction.
If $(x,y)$ is a backward edge (meaning: it's in the residual graph because of an antiparallel $(y,x)$ in the original graph that has positive flow) then there exists an edge $(y,x)$ in the original graph with $f(y,x)>0$. However, backward edges through minimum cuts have a flow of $0$, and $(y,x)$ is such an edge, so this is once again a contradiction.
Thus, either way we end up with contradiction, and so our assumption was incorrect and this concludes this side of the proof.

$\Rightarrow$:
We assume no residual path exists from $u$ to $v$, and want to show that $(u,v)$ is in some minimum cut.
Due to time limitations I don't consider the case where $s=v$ and instead simply assume that $s \neq v$.
Indeed: let the flow be maximum, and let $(u,v)$ be an edge such that no path from $u$ to $v$ exists in the residual graph.
Suppose $(u,v)$ is not in any minimum cut (*). Let $S=\left\{ s,u \right\}$. Since $u \in S$ and $v \in \bar{S}$, it holds that $(u,v)$ crosses the cut $S$ (shorthand for $(S, \bar{S})$); and due to our assumption (*), this implies that $S$ is not a minimum cut. For this reason, there exists a forward edge in the residual graph (see bullet point #1 appended to this answer); denote it $e=(x,y)$ (so $x\in S$, $y\in\bar{S}$).
Suppose $y=v$. Since $f(u,v)>0$ (see bullet point #2) it holds that there is a "flow path" – a path composed of edges with positive flow – from $s$ to $u$ (since outgoing flow through $u$ is positive, so is incoming flow, and so flow must reach $u$ through $s$ – rather trivial but can be shown e.g. inductively); but in that case, its "inverse path" in the residual network (the path with all edges flipped and with residual capacities = flow of original edges) exists and constitutes a path from $u$ to $s$, so if $x=s$ we have the following path in the residual network:
$$
u \leadsto s = x\underset{e}{\underbrace{\rightarrow}}y=v
$$
Whereas if $x=u$ we have the following path in the residual network:
$$
u = x\underset{e}{\underbrace{\rightarrow}}y=v
$$
So either way we end up with a path from $u$ to $v$, which contradicts our assumption; so indeed, $y \neq v$. We set $S \leftarrow S \cup \left\{ y \right\}$ (so now both $x$ and $y$ are in $S$). Note that this means that $v$ is still in $\bar{S}$ so $(u,v)$ still crosses the cut, which means that, by our assumption, it is still not minimum.
Now, inductively until we reach an edge whose destination is $t$: assume that we've already added $\ell$ nodes to the base $S=\left\{ s,u \right\}$, that $S$ is still a minimum cut, and that it holds that each node in $S$ is reachable from the previously added node in the residual network. (The base case was shown above: we can either choose to view $y$ was the first node added to the base $S$ and so there is no "previous node"; or we can slightly refine our claim such that $u$ is the first one we consider in this string of nodes, and so $y$ was the first one added and it is indeed reachable from $u$, its predecessor, as shown before.)
We thus use a similar argument to prove the induction step. $S$ is not minimum so there exists a forward edge in the residual graph; denote it $(j,k)$. Since $j \in S$, we know a path exists from the previously added node, denoted $b$, to $j$ by the induction hypothesis (also: $b$ is reachable from $u$ due to the transitivity of "reachability"), and so if $k=v$ then a path exists from $u$ to $v$: $$u \leadsto y \leadsto b \leadsto j \rightarrow k=v$$ This in contradiction to our base assumption that no such path exists; so $k \neq v$ (meaning if we add it then $e$ still crosses the cut so it is still minimum). Furthermore, it also holds that $k$ is reachable from $j$, so since $j$ is reachable from $b$ (by the hypothesis), $k$ is also reachable from $b$: $b\leadsto j \rightarrow k$. This concludes the induction, but it also brings us to yet another contradiction: the graph is finite and on every iteration we add a new node to $S$, so after some finite amount of iterations of this, we reach a node whose target is $t$, in which case we've just shown that there exists a residual path from $u$ to $t$ (as stated, we find an edge $(\alpha, t)$ when we stop, with $alpha$ being reachable from $y$, being a node added before it in the induction process: $ x \rightarrow y \leadsto \alpha \rightarrow t$), and so if $x=u$ then we have the path $x=u \leadsto t$; we also have a path from $t$ to $v$ due to a description similar to the one under bullet point #1 ($(u,v)$ is saturated, so has positive flow through it; thus, it is on a "flow path" between $s$ and $t$ that goes through $u$ and $v$, and due to the "inverse path" existing in the residual network, this gives us a residual path from $t$ to $s$ through $v$ and $u$ – a subpath of which is a path from $t$ to $v$), so we find $u \leadsto t \leadsto v$, which contradicts our assumption about no such path existing. Thus, $x=s$ (since that was the only other option for $x$'s identity), but we've shown a path from $x$ to $t$, so a path exists from $s$ to $t$ in the residual network. This is an augmenting path, which contradicts our flow being maximal.
This is then a contradiction to our assumption that $e$ crosses no minimum cuts, so this side of the proof is also concluded. $\blacksquare$

As stated, "forward edge in the residual graph" refers to an edge whose source node is in $S$ and destination node is in $\bar{S}$. This claim holds because a cut $S$ is minimum $\iff$ all forward edges that cross it are saturated and all backward edges are with a flow of $0$, so if $S$ is not minimum then there exists either an unsaturated forward edge or a backward edge with a positive flow; if the former holds then the residual graph has a forward edge with a residual capacity of $c(e)-f(e)$, and if the latter holds then there is a forward edge with a residual capacity of $f(e)$, so either way such an edge exists.
Edge $(u,v)$ exists in the graph. If there is no path from $u$ to $v$ in the residual network, then $(u,v)$ itself cannot be in the residual network since otherwise it constitutes a path, so $(u,v)$ must be saturated, and so it definitely has positive flow: $f(u,v)=c(u,v)>0$.


I'd like to note that: 1) this answer is basically an adapted version of a draft I wrote for myself to prove this, and so is somewhat needlessly messy, probably; and 2) that I used in it the property that in a minimum cut all forward edges are saturated and all backward edges have a flow of $0$; the proof of this claim is simple and can be found in many places online (and on StackExchange), such as here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237008/a-cut-is-minimal-iff-forward-arcs-saturated-and-reverse-arcs-flowless

I'd appreciate any feedback/corrections to this proof, of course.
